# Upnp/c# Fail send event

Tags: c#, upnp, dlna

I'm trying to build an upnp device in c#. I have implemented the subscriber but when I try to notify variable state change, the message didn't listen.
To test the subscription and event, I'm using Device Spy by Intel.

Here the code to send the notification:

```
try
        {
            HostName host = new HostName(hostName);
            StreamSocket _socket = new StreamSocket();

            await _socket.ConnectAsync(host, portNumber.ToString());

            var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            DataWriter dw = new DataWriter(_socket.OutputStream);
            dw.WriteString(message);
            await dw.StoreAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Here the send packet:

```
NOTIFY /65088E88-1082-4AC9-98D2-111DF151507D/urn:upnp-org:serviceId:ACDLServiceID HTTP/1.1
HOST: 10.10.50.161:58583
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
CONTENT-LENGHT: 126
NT: upnp:event
NTS: upnp:propchange
SID: uuid:8937a19d-bf7b-4903-8875-e5992abe975b
SEQ: 0

<e:propertyset xmlns:e="urn:schemas-upnp-org:event-1-0"><e:property><led_state>Acceso</led_state></e:property></e:propertyset>
```

What's the problem?
Thank you

Comment: `What's the problem?` Indeed. A socket is connected, a message is written, and you've verified that the message is sent. So, where's the problem?

Comment: Sended message are not listened from Device Spy. The Controller doesn't show the state variable change.
For other upnp device (like samsung tv) it works fine.